# Changing the background image of an HTML select menu when opened

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom select menu for a form which uses a background image as a downward arrow button. I achieve this effect with this CSS:

```
.calculator_select select {
    background: url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat right 65px top -3px #95957A;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 110%;
    padding: 5px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 25px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.calculator_select select:focus {
    background: url(../img/arrow-flipped.png) no-repeat right 65px top -1px #95957A;
}
```

This works almost perfectly except that the CSS remains in the focused state once an option has been selected and only returns to the first state when the user focuses on another element. Is there some way around this? i.e. CSS is only in the second state when the menu is open? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to achieve an hover effect? why not use select:hover?

Comment: `select:active` might be more suited to what he wants.

Comment: Basically I'm aiming for an effect where when the menu is closed the css will be in the first state (with background arrow.png), when I click the select menu and drop down appears it will change to the second state (with background image arrow-flipped.png) and when I select an option or close the menu in some other way it will return to the original state. When I use select:active the arrow flips for around half a second and then changes back. Focus almost works except the arrow remains flipped until the user selects another element.

Answer (score 0):

For slaps and giggles, I took a shot and came up with an inelegant solution - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/88hL6/).

In this code, you determine which of your ul elements will give a dropdown, and use that element definition to trigger a mouseover/mouseout sequence.

JS
$

```
( 'nav ul li:nth-child(2)' ).mouseover(function(){
        $('.statusdiv').css('background-color', 'green');
});
$( 'nav ul li:nth-child(2)' ).mouseout(function(){
        $('.statusdiv').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Again, more of a brute-force approach, but perhaps it will give others some ideas to make it better.